# I just applied for a credit card. Will I be able to see my credit score number with a decision?

Tags: credit-score

Will I be able to see the actual credit score number the credit card company uses? Or will it just be an accept/reject letter?

Comment: I don't know about recent rules, but in the past the rule was that if you get a rejection you can request a free copy of your credit report. Not the score, but the report. The letter will include the number to call to get the report.

Answer (score 1):

Not all companies use the same scoring model, so if under the new rules, you get a notification of your score, the number might be a different scale.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_score_(United_States)

Just be aware of this so you can compare apples to apples.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the score, but not on-line, in a letter later on. But, as mentioned by others, it doesn't necessarily have to be the FICO score, different lenders use different scores. They must tell you where did they get the score from, and what it is, though.

Answer (score 0):

My experience shows you get just the decision, without any accompanying information, but this may be old news since there are [new regulations](http://www.federalreserve.gov/consumerinfo/wyntk_notices.htm) since 2011 that require lenders to give you credit score information. I did not personally ask for credit in 2011 yet so I don't know how good is the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I just received a new credit card, and didn't get my credit score. Maybe if you aren't approved, then you get your score?